# C++ protected ctor not available to members in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

If I declare a derived class which also includes an additional member of base type, I get a `"constructor is protected"` error.

**test.cpp:**

```
class Base { protected: Base() {} };

class Derived1 : public Base
  {
    Derived1()  {}
  };

class Derived2 : public Base
  {
    Derived2()  {}
    Base    other_base;
  };
```

**$ g++ test.cpp**

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Derived2::Derived2()’:
test.cpp:3:25: error: ‘Base::Base()’ is protected
 class Base { protected: Base() {} };
                         ^
test.cpp:12:14: error: within this context
  Derived2()  {}
```

If I declare `Derived2` as a friend of Base, the error goes away. Can anyone explain what's happening here?

TIA.

Comment: When you declare an object, you use it's (public) interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Derived2` contains an instance of `Base`.

Accessibility of protected members is only in the context of a derived class instance accessing members it has inherited.   It does not allow construction of members with protected constructors.

Therefore `Derived2`'s constructor cannot construct `other_base`, but can construct the `Base` it inherits from.

Declaring `Derived2` as a `friend` of `Base` allows `other_base` to be constructed.

Comment: Ah, I thought inheritance was more like friendship than it actually is. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

It's because `other_base` is not actually part of the `Derived2` class, it's a separate object that follows the normal rules for public/protected/private members.

Answer (score 1):

In your example other_base is treated like a member of your `Derived2` class, and it follows normal access rules. The only place where you can call your protected `Base()` ctor is initzialization list of `Derived2` ctor:

> Derived2() : Base() {}

If u want use protected/private methods/members use `friend` keyword.